# Azure Cosmos Document DB - Cannot view documents that have been created using API from Data Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

When I add Documents to Azure Cosmos Document DB using the API's, I cannot view those documents using Data Explorer.
I can read the documents from the API's though, and Azure Document DB Studio lists them as well.

However if I try to view them from within Azure Cosmos Document DB Data Explorer, nothing appears.

If I add a Document directly from within Data Explorer, it appears from within Data Explorer, and is returned from my code as well.

Wandering what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: What API's? Is there a specific API? Table? DocumentDB? MongoDB? Graph? Right now, as written, it's impossible to know what you've actually done. Please edit your question to clarify. It would also help if you showed a snippet of code that adds documents (and that you're able to query those documents). And it would help to show how you're using the data explorer (I'm assuming you're using the in-browser explorer, correct?).

Comment: I have the same problem! I'm using the MongoDB API from my application, where I can add, remove and query the documents just fine. But I can't see them in the portal. If I look at the traffic between the Azure Portal client and the server, I can see that these requests fail with HTTP error code 500 after 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Firewall settings for your Cosmos DB account. Since Microsoft recently changed the IP address of the Azure Portal, you would need to allow the portal's new IP address to talk to Cosmos DB.